# PDF Background / Watermark / Stationery with fpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

is there a (easy?) way to use a exist stationery-pdf in fpdf?

At this moment my generated pdf use this code to add my stationery (as a background) in my generated invoice:

```
function Header() {
    $this->Image('stationery.jpg',0,0,210,0);
}
```

But now, i need to add a pdf (stationery.pdf) instead of the .jpg.

Comment: A lazy solution would be to turn the PDF into a JPG and use that.

Comment: [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) allows you to use existing pdfs as templates, watermarks, etc; I don't think it can do so limited to the header, but that may not be a major problem. (FPDI can be used with TCPDF)